# Autobahn with asyncio - Unable to create connection for URL's with paths

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, autobahn

I am trying to connect to two WebSockets (WebSocket A with URI wss://domainA.com and WebSocket B with URI wss://domainB.com/path) using Autobahn running on asyncio as described in the [Autobahn docs](http://autobahn.ws/python/websocket/programming.html#connection-lifecycle).

I have created a WebSocketClientProtocol like so:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol

class ClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, response):
        print("Connected to Server: {}".format(response.peer))
```

and am connecting to the WebSocket using an asyncio connection:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory
import asyncio

factory = WebSocketClientFactory()
factory.protocol = ClientProtocol

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

coro = loop.create_connection(factory, 'domainA.com', 80)

loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

I am able to connect to WebSocket A  but connecting to WebSocket B by replacing `domainA.com` with `domainB.com/path` results in an error `gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.`

I know that WebSocket B is working since I am able to connect to it using a different library. Also, replacing `domainB.com/path` with just `domainB.com` results in `connection was closed uncleanly (WebSocket connection upgrade failed (301 - MovedPermanently))`

Comment: Does `len("wss://domainB/path")` returns what you expect it to return? Check your code - delete the string `"DomainB/path/`" and rewrite it from scratch: . it might include an invisible unicode character